# analytically continuing a function into a two-leaf function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-cuts

My function is defined as

$$f(z) = \int_0^\infty  \frac{\rho(x)  dx}{x-z } , $$

where $\rho(x)$ is a real function. It is easy to see that $f$ has a branch cut along the positive real axis. Now let us do analytic continuation, i.e., let $z$ make an anticlockwise circle around the origin starting from $x - i 0^+ $. The problem is, for what $\rho$, when $z$ comes back to $x + i 0^+$, the value of $f$ will agree with the value defined above? In short, for what $\rho$, can $f$ extend into a nice two-leaf function?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid bothering with convergence issues, I'll assume that $\rho(x)$ is continuous and $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty |\rho(x)|\,\text{d}x$ converges.

What you can do is to look at

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\rho(x)}{x-z}-\dfrac{\rho(x)}{x-\overline{z}}\,\text{d}x$

$=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \dfrac{(z-\overline{z})\rho(x)}{|x-z|^2}\,\text{d}x$

which, for $z=a+bi$ where $a>0$ and $b>0$, can be rewritten as

$=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \dfrac{2bi\rho(x)}{(x-a)^2+b^2}\,\text{d}x$

which tends to $2\pi i\rho(a)$ as $b\to0^+$.

Comment: This I know. I know there is a jump across the positive real axis.